# Invoke / click a mailto link with JQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

I'd like to invoke a [mailto](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) link from JavaScript - that is I'd like a method that allows me to open the email client on the users PC, exactly as if they had clicked on a normal mailto link.

How can I do this?

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gaboom/h81qov5g/

Comment: try `<button onclick="window.open('mailto:KingRider<contato@sandroalvares.com.br>');">Contact me</button>`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` here, like this:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";
```

Comment: and how would I append a body? mailto:address@dmail.com?body=myBody and mailto:address@dmail.com&amp;myBody do not work for me...

Comment: @jipiboily, can you please explain more? Which browser have you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: @Adnan from what I remember it doesn't work with Opera and maybe more browsers. Depending on your needs, you might be able to workaround that problem.

Comment: @Rolf I just tested in the latest chrome stable, still working.

Comment: Can it be done without openning a new tab or changing any window visible content:  window.location.href = "tel:+4812345";   ?

Comment: Max, you have likely figured this out, but for future readers: `window.location.href = 'mailto:address@dmail.com&subject=Hello there&body=This is the body';`.  Not `?` and not `&amp;`, just `&`

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid the blank page issue discussed above by instead using .click() with a link on the page:

```
document.getElementById('mymailto').click();
...
<a href="mailto:...." id="mymailto" style="display:none"></a>
```

Comment: I tried this: `      function Call(){
            document.getElementById('mymailto').click();
        }
    
    
    <a href="tel:+48123456" id="mymailto" style="display:none"></a>` and the new tab still opens.

Answer (score 6):

the working answer for me, tested in chrome, IE and firefox together with outlook was this

```
window.location.href = 'mailto:address@dmail.com?subject=Hello there&body=This is the body';
```

`%0d%0a` is the new line symbol of the email body in a mailto link

`%20` is the space symbol that should be used, but it worked for me as well with normal space

Answer (score 3):

Better to use

`window.open('mailto:address@mail.com?subject=sub&body=this is body')`

If we use `window.location.href` chrome browser is having error in network tab with Provisional headers are shown
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you @Prabin Tp

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a possibillity to avoid the empty page.

I found out, you can simply insert an iframe with the mailto link into the dom.
This works on current Firefox/Chrome and IE (also IE will display a short confirm dialog).

Using jQuery, I got this:

```
var initMailtoButton = function()
{
    var iframe = $('<iframe id="mailtoFrame" src="mailto:name@domain.com" width="1" height="1" border="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    var button = $('#mailtoMessageSend');    
    if (button.length > 0) {            
        button.click(function(){
            // create the iframe
            $('body').append(iframe);
            //remove the iframe, we don't need it any more
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                iframe.remove();    
            }, 500);

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I combined several Stack Overflows to come up with this function:

```
//this.MailTo is an array of Email addresses
//this.MailSubject is a free text (unsafe) Subject text input
//this.MailBody is a free text (unsafe) Body input (textarea)
//SpawnMail will URL encode /n, ", and ', append an anchor element with the mailto, and click it to spawn the mail in the users default mail program
SpawnMail: function(){
    $("#MyMailTo").remove();
    var MailList="";
    for(i in this.MailTo)
        MailList+=this.MailTo[i]+";";
    var NewSubject=this.MailSubject.replace(/\n/g, "%0d%0a");
    NewSubject=NewSubject.replace(/"/g, "%22");
    NewSubject=NewSubject.replace(/'/g, "%27");
    var NewBody=this.MailBody.replace(/\n/g, "%0d%0a");
    NewBody=NewBody.replace(/"/g, "%22");
    NewBody=NewBody.replace(/'/g, "%27");
    $("#mainNavBar").after("<a id='MyMailTo' style='display:none;' href='mailto:"+MailList+"?subject="+NewSubject+"&body="+NewBody+"'>&nbsp;</a>");
    document.getElementById('MyMailTo').click();
}
```

The cool part about this (and how I plan to use it) is I can put this in a loop and split out individual messages to everyone in the array or keep everyone together (which is what this function currently does).
Anyway thanks for the tip @Toskan

**FOLLOW-UP** - Please note the new HTML5 standard does not allow looping mailto (or other pop-up related js) without a "required user gesture". Cool article here: https://github.com/WICG/interventions/issues/12
So you can't use this to mass generate individual e-mails, but it does work well with sending to many in it's current design.