# Automatically launching the user's email software in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc4 application, in which I have this view:

```
<form action ="\Home\Index" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" name="mail" value="launch mail" />
</form>
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I'd like to launch the default mailing software on the pc (i.e outlook, thunderbird, etc.) when I click the submit button.

So how can I modify the action in the controller to automatically launch the mailing software?

Comment: You can just do this on the client, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868315/invoke-click-a-mailto-link-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: i'd a version of `mailto` in C#

Comment: Now that I think about it a little more, doing it on the *server* doesn't make a lot of sense anyway because you are trying to open a *client* application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reliable way to force the launching of any program on a client machine.  Imagine: that would be a huge security risk if webpages could just force the running of applications.

You can use [`mailto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto), which is basically a shortcut that tells the host PC "hey, launch your e-mail application and put this info in an e-mail; BUT the behavior once it reaches the host PC isn't always consistent.

To put a simple mailto link into your razor syntax:

```
<a href="mailto:support@YourDomain.com">E-mail support</a>
```

Or if you wanted to get fancy, if your model has an e-mail address:

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.EmailAddress">@Model.EmailAddress</a>
```