# How to prevent page from jumping to top of page with mailto link in an anchor?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an anchor link with `mailto:example@email.com` as href, but it jumps to the top of the page when it is clicked. I want to prevent that from happening.

I tried `e.preventDefault()` in my js, which works but has the problem that it won't open the email client anymore.

scenario:

I have a "Get in Touch"  link at the bottom of my page. It should open the email client (which is working). The problem is that it jumps to top of page everytime it is clicked. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

here is what the anchor link look like:

```
<a class="get-in-touch" href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Get In Touch</a>
```

here is what I tried already.

```
$(".get-in-touch").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

but that didn't work. Still jumps to top of page.

Comment: Try e.preventDefault() in function

Comment: Please put together a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem so that we can see exactly the problem you are having and may attempt to help you out.

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()` on the `click` event and then use `window.location.href="your link"` in the same event

Comment: @Code_Ninja already tried that it didn't work, still jump to top of page.

Comment: @Code_Ninja thanks for the response, if you have other ideas please let me know, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `window.location.assign("your URL")` instead of `window.location.href` in the suggestion given above by me.

Comment: @Code_Ninja no luck, it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
<a class="get-in-touch" href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Get In Touch</a>
```

Write the following:

```
<a class="get-in-touch" href="#" onclick="window.open('mailto:email@gmail.com')">Get In Touch</a>
```

This will work surely.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868315/invoke-click-a-mailto-link-with-jquery-javascript) is another stackoverflow question regarding your problem.

Here is the link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31qeLrp4/3/).

Comment: It works , thanks a lot.
Really appreciate the effort

Comment: If you have found a solution, then please select an answer or upvote/downvote it.